# How many kinds of timestamp formats does CnosDB support? Can you give me an example？

Tags: database, time-series

Generally, we use the rfc3339_date_time_string in CnosDB to specify the time. But I wonder that are there any else kinds of timestamp formats that valid in CnosDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation, only the RCF3339 standard is currently supported.[doc/data-type](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/query/data_type.html#constant.)

[image]

Comment: Could you share the official documentation link?

Comment: https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/query/data_type.html#constant.

Comment: could you update the answer to include the link?

Comment: I have modified my answer with doc-link and image.